# Sorting html table with jquery - form stops working and can't pass new order to php file - help please

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I can get my data table to propegate just like I want. I can also pass everything I need to when I click submit. The problem is this:

I have dabbled with using jquery to sort the table to make it easier to use. While I can make it sort, doing so kills the form. I also can't seem to find a way to store the new sort order and pass this along also.

As you will see - I've gone back to the basic code that works - removing the useless failed attempts to make this work.

My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<form action="formAction.php" method="post">
<table border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="sort" class="grid">
<tr>
<td colspan="16" align="center" valign="middle"><h1><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">All In-Progress Units</font></strong></h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">#</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Last 4 of VIN</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Invoice Number</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Customer</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Model</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Length</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Dress Wall</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Floor</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Upper Color</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Lower Color</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Rear Door</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Drawing</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Overall Status</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Detailed Status</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Edit Unit</font></strong></h2></td>
<td align="center"><h2><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Remove</font></strong></h2></td>
</tr>

<?php

/*Stuff to connect to the database goes here */

$query="SELECT * FROM masterschedule ORDER BY BuildOrder ASC";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

    $newNumOrder = $i + 1;

    $InvoiceNumber=mysql_result($result,$i,"InvoiceNumber");
    $OverallProgress=mysql_result($result,$i,"OverallProgress");
    $BuildOrder=mysql_result($result,$i,"BuildOrder");
    $Trailer = mysql_query("SELECT Model, Length, DressWall, Floor, UpperColor, LowerColor, RearDoor, Name, Last4 from invoices WHERE InvoiceNumber = '$InvoiceNumber'");
    $Info = mysql_fetch_array($Trailer);
    $Model = $Info['Model'];
    $Length = $Info['Length'];
    $DressWall = $Info['DressWall'];
    $Floor = $Info['Floor'];
    $UpperColor = $Info['UpperColor'];
    $LowerColor = $Info['LowerColor'];
    $RearDoor = $Info['RearDoor'];
    $Name = $Info['Name'];  
    $Last4 = $Info['Last4'];

    $panelStatus=mysql_result($result,$i,"panelStatus");
    $platformStatus=mysql_result($result,$i,"platformStatus");
    $boxStatus=mysql_result($result,$i,"boxStatus");
    $componentStatus=mysql_result($result,$i,"componentStatus");
    $roofStatus=mysql_result($result,$i,"roofStatus");
    $assemblyStatus=mysql_result($result,$i,"assemblyStatus");
    $washStatus=mysql_result($result,$i,"washStatus");
    $weldOneStatus=mysql_result($result,$i,"weldOneStatus");
    $weldTwoStatus=mysql_result($result,$i,"weldTwoStatus");
    $weldThreeStatus=mysql_result($result,$i,"weldThreeStatus");
    $lastLookStatus=mysql_result($result,$i,"lastLookStatus");
    $cutStatus=mysql_result($result,$i,"cutStatus");

    $orderClean = "UPDATE masterschedule SET BuildOrder='$newNumOrder' WHERE InvoiceNumber='$InvoiceNumber'";
    mysql_query($orderClean);

    if ($panelStatus == 'DONE' && $platformStatus == 'DONE' && $boxStatus == 'DONE' && $componentStatus == 'DONE' && $roofStatus == 'DONE' && $assemblyStatus == 'DONE' && $washStatus == 'DONE' && $weldOneStatus == 'DONE' && $weldTwoStatus == 'DONE' && $weldThreeStatus == 'DONE' && $lastLookStatus == 'DONE' && $cutStatus == 'DONE') {
    $statusChange = "UPDATE masterschedule SET OverallProgress='DONE' WHERE InvoiceNumber='$InvoiceNumber'";
    mysql_query($statusChange);
    $invoiceChange = "UPDATE invoices SET Status='DONE' WHERE InvoiceNumber='$InvoiceNumber'";
    mysql_query($invoiceChange);
    $OverallProgress = 'DONE';
    }




?>

<tr>
<td width="10%" align="center" class="index"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $BuildOrder; ?></font></td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $Last4; ?></font></td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $InvoiceNumber; ?></font></td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $Name; ?></font></td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $Model; ?></font></td>
<td width="5%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $Length; ?></font></td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $DressWall; ?></font></td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $Floor; ?></font></td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $UpperColor; ?></font></td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $LowerColor; ?></font></td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $RearDoor; ?></font></td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="drawings/<?php echo $InvoiceNumber; ?>.pdf">pdf</a></font></td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $OverallProgress; ?></font></td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=24&other=<?php echo $InvoiceNumber; ?>">Click Here</a></font></td>

<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=20&other=<?php echo $InvoiceNumber; ?>">Click Here</a></font></td>
<td width="10%" align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><input type="checkbox" name=<?php echo $InvoiceNumber; ?> value="yes"></font></td>
</tr>


<?php


$i++;
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
// JavaScript Document

var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });
    return $helper;
},
    updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
        $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).html(i + 1);


        });




    };



$("#sort tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified,
    stop: updateIndex
}).disableSelection();



</script>
</table>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Save Order">
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Mark Done">
</form>
```

Comment: jQuery UI sortable is to allow the user to drag elements in a list to reorder them. is that what you are looking for or do you want something like clickable headers that sort all rows ascending/descending according to values in that column?

Comment: I need to reorder the list, and then ultimately save this new order to the mysql database. That's where I'm running into problems. I can't seem to find anything that works with what I'm doing online.

Comment: in-line styling `!==` cool

Comment: Haha - If I can get it to work, the cleaning shall begin... This is a compilation of many different thoughts to get where it is now... Sadly, it's not where it needs to be though.

Answer (score 2):

1) Storing the sort order: I have found the best place to store this locally is with a hidden input in the header cells of the column. If you just want to sort by 1 column at a time, then all you would need to do is indicate the sort direction and column identifier. I would also add some up/down arrows in the header cell to indicate to the user what their current sort pattern is. If you want to store multiple consecutive sorts, then you also need to add a hidden input to store the sort order so you can build your query correctly.

2) Sorting table data: It is important that you first check the type of data in each column. Javascript does not effectively sort mixed data as you might intend or expect. First determine if the data is text, numbers, dates etc and perform a datatype specific sort for each.

**EDIT per comment**
OK I have needed to do that before as well. What I did was add a hidden input inside each row that stored the row's index in the table. Using jQuery's [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/), I added an event handler to the `drop` event of sortable that would adjust the value of each of the inputs according to their row's index in the table. The names of each input should indicate to you which item it is referring to then its value will tell you its position.

Comment: I'm hoping that the user can grab a row and drag it up or down to put it where they want. Then they can click save order and the page will post a unique id for each row along with the new order number. I can send the unique id and original number, but once I use this page to drag and drop a row in a new place, complete failure. Nothing passes, and I don't know how to store the new order number.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use forms for this. Use $.getJSON to post your results to the server and

```
var arr = [];
$('tr').each(function(){
     // this is the tr element
     var id = $(this).find('input[name=element_id]').val(); // hidden input named element_id stores your id for each tr
     arr.push(id);
});
```

Comment: I'm missing how to include the new order along with the row id - This doesn't mean the answer isn't right in front of me though!

Comment: .each() should return the <tr> elements in order as they appear on the screen. Thus the array of ids will have your new order. Put a hidden input in your <tr><td>...</td></tr> with the item id (not the order) of the row.